# ReferenceError: self is not defined, on trying to run dev:ssr after adding angular universal to an angular 11

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular11

I have an Angular theme which I used to develop an app and now I'm trying to add Angular universal to it. After adding Angular universal with `ng add @nguniversal/epxress-engine` I tried to run `npm run dev:ssr`, but it's throwing an error which I cannot understand:

```
demo@demo:~/workrepos/my-angular-app$ npm run dev:ssr

> my-angular-app@11.0.0 dev:ssr /home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app
> ng run matngular:serve-ssr

****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files                 | Names                            |      Size
main.js                             | main                             |  10.99 MB

                                    | Initial Total                    |  10.99 MB

Lazy Chunk Files                    | Names                            |      Size
modules-home-home-module.js         | modules-home-home-module         | 198.22 kB
vendors~firebase-auth.js            | vendors~firebase-auth            | 178.74 kB
modules-walkin-walkin-module.js     | modules-walkin-walkin-module     | 112.85 kB
vendors~modules-home-home-module.js | vendors~modules-home-home-module |  39.71 kB

Build at: 2021-07-01T05:06:53.638Z - Hash: 1ab3744b803c567f7b7d - Time: 37736ms
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files             | Names                        |      Size
vendor.js                       | vendor                       |   7.43 MB
polyfills-es5.js                | polyfills-es5                | 770.23 kB
styles.css                      | styles                       | 553.38 kB
main.js                         | main                         | 412.27 kB
polyfills.js                    | polyfills                    | 352.14 kB
scripts.js                      | scripts                      |  12.25 kB
runtime.js                      | runtime                      |   9.13 kB

                                | Initial Total                |   9.49 MB

Lazy Chunk Files                | Names                        |      Size
firebase-auth.js                | firebase-auth                | 255.76 kB
modules-home-home-module.js     | modules-home-home-module     | 243.39 kB
modules-walkin-walkin-module.js | modules-walkin-walkin-module | 111.50 kB
common.js                       | common                       |   3.93 kB

Build at: 2021-07-01T05:07:05.749Z - Hash: e086cd8ba01bfdf5d1a4 - Time: 44578ms

Compiled successfully.
/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:134
    logger: self.console,
            ^

ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at /home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:134:13
    at /home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:130:11
    at Object.+WhS (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:131:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Module.HZ+G (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:117175:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Module.ZAI4 (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:171618:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Module.24aS (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:43843:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/demo/workrepos/my-angular-app/dist/matngular/server/main.js:26:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:46469
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-angular-app@11.0.0 dev:ssr: `ng run matngular:serve-ssr`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-angular-app@11.0.0 dev:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/demo/.npm/_logs/2021-07-01T05_07_11_669Z-debug.log
```

I have been looking all over the internet for any solutions from couple of days but couldn't found anything anywhere similar to this.

Interesting thing is when i tried adding angular universal to a brand new angular application created from cli, it works without any issues..

here is the `angular.json` server section from my angular theme application:

```
 "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/matngular/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "matngular:build",
            "serverTarget": "matngular:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "matngular:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "matngular:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "matngular:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "matngular:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
```

my `tsconfig.server.json`:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/server",
    "target": "es2016",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.server.ts",
    "../server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

I can provide any other details required, just don't want to prolong the question with unnecessary details. I'll be very thankful for any guidance in solving this issue.

Please find the main.js file for referrence:
[main.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GkPfv7ML7nYAH66kyg36GKlHEKMI-KDi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Open the file and tell us what lib does the code (`main.js:134`) belong to

Comment: @David I have updated the question with main.js file for your reference, unfortunately i'm unable to figure out to which lib it belongs to. Here's the code at main.js:134 **bold** `(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

(function(global, factory) {
   true ? factory(exports) : undefined;
})(this, function(exports) {
  "use strict";
  var adapters = {
    logger: self.console,
    WebSocket: self.WebSocket
  };`

Comment: 4 lines above the code you pasted, it's clearly indicated `./node_modules/@rails/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable.js ***!`

Comment: Thanks @David for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, `self` is a window reference which cannot be used in SSR. One of your dependencies is using it. By searching for "logger: self.console" in your main.js, you can see that code originated from

```
./node_modules/@rails/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable.js
```

Try upgrading that dependency to see if it gets resolved. Or you can try to use [isPlatformServer](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformServer) to avoid rendering the offending component on the server.

Comment: Thanks @adam0101, understood the issue. There are several components where window is being used, would have to figure out a way to avoid those components getting exposed to server or something else... Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hi @MohammedSafeeUddin. In the end how did you solve the SSR problem?